# Hortonworks Ambari cannot start data node - Cannot find Java VM / JVM library file

Tags: java-6, ambari

I've just added a new datanode to my Hortonworks cluster (machines running RHEL7), but clearly I must have missed something when I installed Java jdk 1.8 on it. All the node's roles are installed but Datanode, metrics monitor and node manager show up as stopped in the Ambari manager. Whenever I run 'Datanode start' it fails with the following message:

```
==> /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/jsvc.out <==
==> /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/jsvc.err <==
Cannot find any VM in Java Home /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77
Cannot locate JVM library file
```

Output when running java -version (logged in as root):

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

I figure it must be something along the lines of exporting JAVA_HOME or setting PATH, in a way that it looks inside the jdk's bin folder. Can't make it work though. Maybe because I'm exporting to root's bash profile, instead whichever account ambari uses to run datanode start? Any ideas?

Comment: On that new node does this directory exist: `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_77`? Ambari expects java to be installed in the same location on every node.

Comment: The directory exists, yes, and it's the same one used by the existing data nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out Ambari doesn't automatically 'see' the changes you make to the jdk (if like me you have been messing with it). To solve this I recommissioned the datanode, and then restarted it. It then worked right away.